# If impossible to modify header in JSONP. How does twitter extension in Chrome work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, jsonp, cross-domain-policy

Now I'm working to do twitter client with Javascript.
After I read this topic, I have question

[Modify HTTP Headers for a JSONP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350778/modify-http-headers-for-a-jsonp-request)

He told impossible way to modify HTTP Header when using JSONP.
If it's true. How does twitter extension work in Chrome ?
I think Chrome extension use Javascript, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extensions have more privileges then "normal" JavaScript code executing within a page. Check here:

- http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html