# Twitter API Error: 'internal server error'

Tags: javascript, twitter, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-extension, twitter-oauth

I tried to use Twitter API to post a tweet using Javascript. Details Below

**Base String**

> POST&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D9acc2f75c97622d1d2b4c4fb4124632b1273b0e0%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1305227053%26oauth_token%3D159970118-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DHello

**Header**

> OAuth
>   oauth_nonce="9acc2f75c97622d1d2b4c4fb4124632b1273b0e0",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
>   oauth_timestamp="1305227053",
>   oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
>   oauth_token="159970118-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
>   oauth_signature="IWuyoPJBrfY03Hg5QJhDRtPoaDs%3D",
>   oauth_version="1.0"

I used POST method with body "status=Hello"

But i get a INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.. IS there any mistake on my side ?? Thanks in advance.

Javascript code used

h is the header given above

tweet="Hello"

encodeURLall is user defined which is working in all other occasions.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",h);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhr.readyState == 4 )
    {
        console.log("STATUS="+xhr.status);  
        console.log("RESPONSE="+xhr.responseText);  
    }
}

xhr.send("status="+encodeURLall(tweet));

}
```

Comment: Are you POSTing from the browser? or is there server-side code doing the post?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use?

Comment: @jimbojw i am posting from the browser only.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Have edited the post above with code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If impossible to modify header in JSONP. How does twitter extension in Chrome work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273182/if-impossible-to-modify-header-in-jsonp-how-does-twitter-extension-in-chrome-wor)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Twitter's site using an XMLHttpRequest, due to [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead or a server-side proxy (call your own server that redirects your request to Twitter).

BTW, what does `encodeURLall()` do? Shouldn't you just use `encodeURIComponent`?

---

**Update:** To quote [Google](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html):

> Regular web pages can use the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

Please read on there to see which settings you should change in order to make this work.

Comment: So i should be doing like this `$.ajax({
     'url': 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json',
     'data': { status: encodeURLall(tweet) },
     'type': 'post',
     'success': onUpdateCallback,
     'dataType': 'jsonp'
    });` but how would i set header for the request.

Comment: Btw i am trying to create a Google Chrome Extension. Just wanna give you clear idea on wat i am doing. So is it not possible to set headers in jsonp ???

Comment: @Ram: In a Chrome extension it might be different.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel So you mean XMLHttp Request is possible or JSONP with custom headers in chrome extension?

Comment: @Ram: According to the [link to Google's own description](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) in the dupe, it is.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I already have given permissions for twitter as told in the google site. so i think i should ask Twitter about this. Anyways Thank you.