# Build an ajax request with jquery, add header and body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

How can I build a Jquery request with $.ajax or $.post with those information:

```
POST /CreateSpeech HTTP/1.1

Host: tts.eu-west-1.ivonacloud.com

Content-type: application/json

X-Amz-Date: 20130913T092054Z

Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=12345/20130913/eu-west-1/tts/aws4_request, 

SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, 

Signature=38c394cf938da94ec503f501a91055bc9aa339d165695884b9e7e60128f6ad27

x-amz-content-sha256: f43e25253839f2c3feae433c5e477d79f7dfafdc0e4af19a952adb44a60265ba

Content-Length: 32

{"Input":{"Data":"Hello world"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100294/json-post-with-customized-httpheader-field)

You need to add the header information in the headers property (dont put in the first line) and then the content as you would normally do in the data property.