# How to use header with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a login checker using jQuery and Ajax, i'm calling query.php which verifies the username and password. And if they don't match, an alert will be shown, and if they are correct it will redirect the user to the other page.
The error message works just fine.
The problem is that when i enter correct username and password, the page doesn't redirect.
In my case i'm been redirected twice, from login.php to query.php then to groupes.php or seance.php

query.php

```
<?php
require('queries/dbsetup.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$type = "";
if (empty($username) || empty($password)) { ?>
    <script>
        sweetAlert("Oops...", "Veuillez remplir tous les champs !", "error");
    </script>
<?php
} else {
echo $type;
switch ($_POST['type']) {
case 'etudiant' : $type = 'etudiant';break;
case 'enseignant' :$type = 'enseignant';break;
}

// Check the username and password
$query = "SELECT username FROM ".$type." where username = '".$username."' AND password ='".$password."' ;";
$set = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$run = mysqli_fetch_array($set);
$id = $run['username'];

// Save the type
$_SESSION['type'] = $type;


if (!empty($id)) {
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $username;

switch ($type) {
case 'etudiant':
header('location: ../groupes.php',true);exit;break;
    case 'enseignant':
header('location: ../seance.php',true);exit;break;

}

} else { ?>
    <script>
        sweetAlert("Oops...", "Le nom d'utilisateur et le mot de passe ne sont pas identique !", "error");
    </script>
    <?php
}
}

?>
```

login.php

```
<form action="query.php" method="post" id="e1" class="">
              <h4>Nouvelle seance</h4>
              <input name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" class="form-control">
              <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-control">
              <input name="type" placeholder="Type" type="text" class="form-control"> 
              <button id="login">Login</button>                 
              <p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

login.js

```
$('#e1').submit(function(){
 return false;
});

$('#login').click(function(){
 $.post(
 $('#e1').attr('action'),
 $('#e1 :input').serializeArray(),
 function(result){
 $('#result').html(result);
 }
 );
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Post with Customized HTTPHeader Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100294/json-post-with-customized-httpheader-field)

Comment: (slightly offtopic) I'd highly suggest you to use PHP PDO - and also sanitize your `$_POST` using `filter_input` instead...

Comment: And where is the element with id `#login` in your html??

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Using MySQLi is fine - why change APIs entirely when MySQLi supports parameterized queries? (Albeit, the PDO syntax is way easier, its personal opinions mostly). And while filtering might be appropriate, using parameterized queries with placeholders is the only way to go for handling user-input in a query. An added note to OP; passwords really shouldn't be stored in plaintext.

Comment: Problem solved with the next reply, thank you all ^^

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef recheck my code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior by telling the client to load the new page via javascript.

You can change these lines

```
switch ($type) {
    case 'etudiant':
        header('location: ../groupes.php',true);exit;break;
    case 'enseignant':
        header('location: ../seance.php',true);exit;break;
}
```

To

```
switch ($type) {
    case 'etudiant':
        ?>
        <script>
            window.location = "../groupes.php";
        </script>
        <?php
        exit;
        break;
    case 'enseignant':
        ?>
        <script>
            window.location = "../seance.php";
        </script>
        <?php
        exit;
        break;
}
```

Comment: if you are using `ajax` request to verify login, Then how this `javascript window.location` will redirect user inside the requested php page?

Comment: It Works man !!!! I don't why but it WORKS thank you very much, but could you explain to me why it didn't work with PHP header function ?

Comment: You can't do a redirect from a POST request. Your Ajax call puts the response in the body, it gets executed by the browser. `window.location` simply instructs the browser to load the specified URL