# How to send header by using jQuery's $.post()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending post request to API and I need to send headers (without using ajax).
i have following code:

```
$.post( URL, data );
```

How to send headers using jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Post with Customized HTTPHeader Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100294/json-post-with-customized-httpheader-field)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post({
     url: 'foo/bar',
     headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
$.post({
     url: 'xyz',
     headers: { 'header': 'value' }
});
```