# how can i restrict the access to only ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

i load inicio.jade with ajax req

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:'/inicio',
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
}).done(function(web)
{
    $('#contenido_nav_principal').fadeOut(600,function()
    {
        $('#contenido_nav_principal').empty();
        $('#contenido_nav_principal').html(web);
        $('#navegacion').animate({height:'600px'},200);
        $('#contenido_nav_principal').fadeIn(600);
    });
});
```

from this address in the server

```
app.get('/inicio',routes.inicio.inicio);
```

the problem is that i can access to the page with http://www.mypage.com/inicio

how can i restrict the access only to ajax requests and redirect to 404 error page if is not an ajax request

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With expressjs, you can respond only to xhr requests like this:

```
function handleOnlyXhr(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.xhr) return next();
  res.send({ "answer": "only is sent with xhr requests"});
}
```

(in your example, `routes.inicio.inicio` would use the pattern above by checking `req.xhr`)

Answer (score 2):

You can detect whether it is an Ajax request at the server side by checking `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header. The value of `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header should be `XmlHttpRequest` if it is an Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `beforeSend` event on the `.ajax()` call.  Per [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can add custom headers to the request.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header) gives an example.

Then you can have your page check for the presence of that custom header.

Comment: That will stop casual users, but there are browser extensions that allow you to add custom headers in at least Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @StevenBurnap So what you are saying is that if someone is bound and determined to go to that URL they can reverse engineer what you are doing and get access to it?  Really?!