# How to add header for all RESTAdapter ember requests

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The API needs to specify api version `application/vnd.api+json;version=1`, also it needs secure x-app-id and x-app-secret. Is there a way to specify that in RESTAdapter in Ember?

After Trying request header

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');
  }
})
```

## SOLUTION

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  bulkCommit: true,
  namespace: 'api',
  headers: { 
   'Accept': 'application/vnd.app+json;version=1',
   'x-appid': '2375498237',
   'x-secret': '238945298235236236236236375923'
  },
  ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    if (this.headers !== undefined) {
      var headers = this.headers;
      hash.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
        Ember.keys(headers).forEach(function(key) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
        });
      };
    }
    return this._super(url, type, hash);
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({ adapter: App.Adapter.create() }); 
App.Store = App.Store.create();
```

## UPDATE #2

The solution mentioned above is no longer needed, as Ember now supports this behavior by default. You only need to supply `headers` and it will automatically be added.

Check out the docs here http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_custom-http-headers

Comment: Not working for me ; when I look at the request, there's no headers in it. Any idea ? A version problem mabye ?

Comment: Do you call 
```App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: App.Adapter.create()
});``` Then ```App.store = App.Store.create();``` After you add the above code?

Comment: Any solutions WITHOUT Ember-Data ?!

Comment: @V-Light It's easy to do using jQuery

Comment: @SeifSallam yeah, I was able to $.ajaxSetup globaly without Ember-Data   with [Ember Initializers](http://mcdowall.info/posts/ember-application-initializers/)

Comment: For people who copy paste: the correct mime-type is [application/vnd.api+json](http://jsonapi.org/#mime-types).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the core the RESTAdapter uses jQuery for Ajax, you can set headers with $.ajaxSetup or a more Ember way with Ember.$.ajaxSetup which would ideally protect you against lower level changes to the API.

jQuery Doc:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

SO with examples:

[How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

Comment: Ok, any ideas on how can i put x-app-secret securely?

Comment: Anything that i can copy-past. I can't get any of those to work in my project. or I don't know how to integrate them.

Comment: App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');
  }
})