# Returning a Cookie value from a web page when called via an jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, cookies

I have a web page that runs on a domain that I own and creates a cookie or returns the value from the previously created cookie.  When I call this page directly, it returns the same value every time (as expected).  When I call this page from a jquery ajax call, it returns a different value each time.

The jquery code:

```
var data = $.ajax({
     type: 'get',
     url: url,
     async: false
}).responseText;
```

The url is a normal aspx page.

I am assuming that the cookie is not being referenced when called from the jquery and therefore the value for the would be created cookie is always being recreated.  What is stopping the cookie from being created?

Comment: Cookie is sent by browser in headers - [add to header](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7686827/304683)

Comment: I'm not trying to send the cookie back, I am trying to reference the cookie on domain-b from a web page on domain-b and return its value to domain-a.