# how to pass headers in jQuery.load like ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been stuck from this issue in couple of days. I want to send some headers data in jQuery.load(). It seems that jQuery.load never send the headers, like ajax. Can somebody explain how to, or Is it necessary? Btw, sory my bad English.

This is the syntax :

```
$loadingBay.load(href, settings.data, function (data, status) {
    prep(status === 'error' ? $tag(div, 'Error').html(settings.xhrError) : $(this).contents());
});
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I think you need to use the plain ajax function. ($.ajax)

Comment: What is the issue with `$.ajax()` is this can't do the job you want to do with `.load()`?

Comment: I have tried, and it was unsuccessfull. The syntax is bellow :
$loadingBay.load(href, settings.data, function (data, status) {
    prep(status === 'error' ? $tag(div, 'Error').html(settings.xhrError) : $(this).contents());
   });

Comment: .load() is a wrapper for .get(), .get() is a wrapper for .ajax(). You can recreate load with the .ajax() method and then add the headers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

Comment: Actually, It's slightly different to my case @Liam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `beforeSend` option in `jquery ajax` , like as follows :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/restTest",
    data: { uname: "asdf" },
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-TOKEN', 'xxxxx');},
    success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
});
```

or can also use `headers` like,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/restTest",
    data: { uname: "asdf" },
    type: "GET",
    headers:{ "X-TOKEN": 'xxxxx'},
    success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Man..You make a great example and clue..God Bless You

Answer (score 8):

You can not pass headers data to `$.load()` , but you can set default setup using `$.ajaxSetup()` like this :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    'headers':{
        'header1':'value1',
        'header2':'value2',
    }
}
);

//give the load call here
$('selector').load('url',function(){
    //do things
})
```

Disclaimer From [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> Its use is not recommended.

The best way is do the is thing using `$.ajax()` :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  headers : {header1 : "header1"}       
  }).done(function(data) {
     $('selector').html(data);
});
```

Comment: that ajax method isn't adding any headers?

Comment: In my case, not all the ajax needs headers. Btw thanks Bro. Nice input for me.