# JSON Web Tokens - attach the token to requests

Tags: json, node.js, token

I am trying to set up an authentication via token for my web app. I am using nodejs for the back end and the jwt-simple module to encode/decode the tokens.

I manage to create and handle the tokens from the server to the client. However I struggle to handle the token from the client to the server.

For example, I have a page called profile for which I handle the requests the following way:

```
  app.get('/profile', [bodyParser(), jwtauth], function(req, res) {

    res.render('profile.ejs', {
      user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
  });
```

Where jwtauth is the following:

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var User = require('../server/models/user');
 
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  var token = (req.user && req.user.access_token) || (req.body && req.body.access_token) || (req.query && req.query.access_token) || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  if (!token)
    return next('invalid or no token');

  try {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token, app.get('jwtTokenSecret'));

    if (decoded.exp <= Date.now())
      return res.end('Access token has expired', 400);

    User.findOne({ _id: decoded.id }, function(err, user) {
      req.user = user;
    });

    return next();

  } catch (err) {
    return next('couldn\'t decode token');
  }

};
```

On the client side I attached the token once the user is logged in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var token = __token;

  if (token) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token
      }
    });
  }
});
```

But if I try to get the url '/profile' in my browser there is no 'x-access-token' in the headers and I get the 'invalid or no token' message.

How can I set the token on the client side so that it is attached to every request to my server?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you seeing when you console.log(req.headers) in your jwtauth middleware? Are you deifning $.ajaxSetup more than once? See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)