# ajax GET not working with Header parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, session, get

First of all I must say that I'm new to AJAX. So the question would sound dumb for most of them 
But the I would really appreciate any kind of help in this
I have been trying to add make an AJAX get request and pass some parameter in the header which fails for some reason.
I know its very basic an issue but I have been searching for a fix for the past 4 hours and couldn't find the right solution

```
function resetSession() {

            $.ajax({

               dataType: "text",
              beforeSend: function (request)
             {
                  request.setRequestHeader("sessionVariable", sessionVariable);
             },
            url: "/reset.php",
            type: "GET",

           success: function(data) {
                 alert("yes");
               },
            error: function(data){
                 alert("no");


              } 
            });



          }
```

I dont see any issues with this code and I did look for a different one that fixes it for me and couldn't find it 
Every time the function is called the request URL is right but **request method is OPTIONS**

Looking forward to an easy fix 
thanks in advance

Comment: @DanielA.White do you mind explaining a bit more or a clear answer??

Comment: I'm writing an answer already :P Google CORS in the meantime.

Comment: thanks @TomášZato 
waiting for that

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning Here it is. Tell me if normal request is working or fails too. In that case, you might not be able to send it at all (unless you have control over the server).

Comment: @TomášZato normal request is working but how do I add parameter to the header in this scenario??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. [I solved it by not using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454340/607407). I think they don't have it covered yet.

Your browser is sending an `OPTIONS` request to find out it the server accepts your request ([retarded, ain't it?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/72207/23080)). [This is a part of CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) (read the whole article if you're interested). The server may decline request with altered headers. `Referrer` header can never be altered.

Try to send normal ajax:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "/reset.php");
req.onload = function() {
      console.log("SUCESS:", this.responseText);
}
req.onerror = function() {
      console.log("FAILURE:", this.status);
}
req.setRequestHeader("sessionVariable", sessionVariable);
req.send(null);
```

I'm not sure what the jQuery `dataType` property is supposed to do. But since you're not sending anything, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I will besending   "request.setRequestHeader("sessionVariable", sessionVariable);"
How do I get to integrate that as well?

Comment: Added, sorry. [Everything about XHR requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) is here. The browsers may not have everything implemented that way.

Comment: I see that your solution worked, but wouldn't it be more correct to alter the server code to have the correct response to the OPTIONS request, i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with`?

Comment: @bvx89 My solution isn't by-passing CORS, it's a legitimate request - not a hack. But thanks for your comment. That explains a lot. But isn't it funny that server must explicitly allow this header - so common among the internet? Do you really think it's correct that there's one more communication step just because of this?

Comment: @TomášZato for some random reason the solution isn't working now 
I was super excited when I got it after 4 hours of searching 
Is there any possible reason that it could go to the previous scenario of  request method : OPTIONS

Comment: I can't tell. If you have it online I can take a look and add whatever I find out to my answer. Did you read the article about CORS? It's really important that you know what you're doing.

Comment: @TomášZato I will read about that 
its working now
The issue turns out to be about req.setRequestHeader("sessionVariable", sessionVariable);
after a refresh of the page it fails but with the session variable its working. very strange  :(

Comment: That will be something on the PHP's end I guess. We're now talking about something that isn't relevant to the topic here. If you need more help, start [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and @mention me in it, I'll eventually reply.

Comment: @TomášZato there was something I had missed when reporting when it go fixed 
I was just way too excited that I neglected that the request method was still OPTIONS when I set the req.setRequestHeader
ELse it is correct as GET.
Is there any other way to set request header??
I guess that would fix my issue

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning The `OPTIONS` will always be called if you call `setRequestheader`. It's written in the document I urged you to read. But if nothing is wrong, the GET request will follow. If something **is** wrong, how can I tell you what it is? You didn't tell me anything about your server.