# Uploadcare Delete via API Issue

Tags: javascript, header, cors, cross-domain, uploadcare

I'm trying to delete an image with the REST API of Uploadcare, I'm doing exactly like the documentation and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439525/how-to-delete-file-s-through-rest-api-in-uploadcare) says, but still can't manage to delete an image, here is my code:

**The html:**

```
<html>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="https://ucarecdn.com/libs/widget/3.2.2/uploadcare.full.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div class="main">

    </div>
    <div>

      <button class="uploader">Upload an image</button>
      <input class="deletet" />
      <button class="getit">delete something</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <footer>Developep by Francisco Jimenez</footer>
</html>
```

The **javascript:**

```
function deleteb(uuid){
 $.ajax({`
    url: "https://api.uploadcare.com/files/"+uuid+"/",`
    type: "DELETE",
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
              "Accept": "application/vnd.uploadcare-v0.5+json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "HEAD, GET, OPTIONS",
             "Authorization": "Uploadcare.Simple publickey:privatekey"
            },
    success: function(result){
      alert("yessss");
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (result){
      alert("ouuuh");
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

The response that i keep getting is: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.uploadcare.com/files/c2e166b5-17b9-493f-bf8c-b33da27842ca~1/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1. this is indeed a CORS issue. make sure your JS libs do not add any arbitrary headers to request.

2. the UUID you're using is Group UUID, not File UUID. So it will not work anyway as

a) the resource URL will give you 404, you need to use /groups/:uuid/
b) there is no DELETE for groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting response CORS headers to the request. This doesn't make sense but more important is that server rejects your requests due to unrecognized headers. For example I get the following error with your code:

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

The following code works perfect for me:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.uploadcare.com/files/8b147fe2-b677-407b-8c28-3d596187ac93/",
  type: "DELETE",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.uploadcare-v0.5+json",
    "Authorization": "Uploadcare.Simple demopublickey:demoprivatekey"
  },
  success: function(result){
    alert("yessss");
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: function (result){
    alert("ouuuh");
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I try the code that you had before i publish this and it didn't work for me, but the UUID that you use doesn't follow the same pattern that the one that I use, i check and in the end the whole thing was because it wasn't a valid UUID

Comment: The thing is that the uuid returned when i upload the image is not the same that i get in the web interfaces of uploadcare