# Ionic 4 Uploadcare ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: firebase, ionic4, uploadcare

I'm getting this error when i try to upload some picture via Ionic 4 using Uploadcare (Cannot display the image because of the error) How could I fix that? Thanks you so much

[image: ERROR]

UPDATED:

Now im having this error without doing anything... don't know why
[image: ANOTHER ERROR]

Comment: there's a typo in host: uploadcore → uploadcare

Comment: also, when you get these kind of errors, check your connectivity first, to be able to ask for help with more context, or, if you're lucky, find out what's wrong by yourself ;)

Comment: I didnt get any conectivity problem

Comment: net::err_connection_refised IS a connectivity problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploadcare Delete via API Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855015/uploadcare-delete-via-api-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it has been resolved... Maybe some cache or something like that (I was also cleaning cache on google), but didnt get any error on Google Chrome, i was constantly doing force-refresh but still the problems before... Now its uploading and didnt get any error. Thanks you so much anyway, i was also restarting the ionic server furthermore...

Answer (score 1):

You're sending extra headers in preflight requests. Most likely this is some framework naively adding headers to all requests disregarding the host.

Comment: there's a better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855015/uploadcare-delete-via-api-issue

Comment: bolshoy spasiva zu pomosch Dmitry, but i dont think so, the problem is following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbIhn45Mjgg&list=PLYxzS__5yYQnpK36-GJjm7IEAuHR7IExa&t=0s&index=5 , and just changing the PUBLIC KEY, used from tutorial, its working! why? i cannot understand this problem

Comment: please read answer for the question I linked. there's an elaborate explanation on what's going on here.

Comment: Sorry its not helpful because im doing Ionic 4 and its quite different (Im not using Ajax)