# Put Http Request in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send a http put request to a api using jquery/js here is what i came up with

```
$.ajax({
type: 'PUT',
dataType: 'json',
url: "http://192.168.x.xxx/api/somerandomusername/lights/1/state",
headers: {"X-HTTP-Method-Override, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *": "PUT"},
data: {"on":true, "sat":255, "bri":255,"hue":10000}
});
```

if i'm using the api debugging tool it's working so my url and data are good 
and i don't have anything showing up in the chrome console.

For more context here is my setup

i'm sending the request to a Philips/hue bridgeusing the url and telling the bulb number 1  this string of data "on":true, "sat":255, "bri":255,"hue":10000.

Comment: Uh, change the `type` from `"POST"` to `"PUT"`?

Comment: Yes sorry that what i did i copy my first version

Comment: Your `headers:` option is not correct. It should be `{"Header1": "Value1", "Header1": "Value2", ...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 'custom-header': 'value' }
});
```

If you want to add a header (or set of headers) to every request then use the beforeSend hook with $.ajaxSetup():

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('custom-header', 'value');
    }
});
```

and you can read on the header properties

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

and a possible duplicate

[How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)