# Setting custom header NAME with jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to set a custom Ajax request header with jQuery has an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655768/1685196).

So, if I do

```
var headervar='testvalue';
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "foo.php",
  headers:{'testname':headervar},
  ...
});
```

It nicely sets headers like

```
[Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.5w-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
[testname] => "testvalue"
[X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest
...
```

However, I like to also set the header **NAME**. If it is hardcoded, like in the example above, it works OK. But if I do this with a variable

```
var headername='testname';
var headervar='testvalue';
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "foo.php",
  headers:{headername:headervar},
  //...
});
```

The result is a header where the variablename suddenly becomes the headername.

```
[Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.5w-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
[headername] => "testvalue"
```

So the question: is it possible to set the headername as a variable in a jQuery Ajax request?

Comment: The usual way to set custom headers to ensure that you are not conflicting  with standards, is to use `x-myName`; in your case `x-testname`. (This is just a guideline not a requirement.) As you can allready see jQuery is setting the custom header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create temporary object for that and use bracket notation to define object property name from variable:

```
var headername='testname';
var headervar='testvar';
var headers_to_set = {};
headers_to_set[ headername ] = headervar;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "foo.php",
  headers:header_to_set,
  //...
});
```

Comment: Hahaha, it took me more time to formulate the question then you to answer it. But it works fine now, thanks!

Comment: @Michel That properly indicate that you asked a good descriptive question.