# Add additional parameter ajax with ajaxsetup not working for contentType json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I want to add a parameter to all the calls that I make to all controllers (asp mvc), with form submit or ajax call, for this I have add to the code:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: { guid : @guidUser }
    });
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='guid' value='"+@guidUser+"' />");
    });
});
```

this work for me, because with the $('form') I add the param guid in all the form submits and with ajaxSetup I put the guid parameter in all the ajax calls, or so thought.

For the majority of my ajax calls, it works, but for one ajax call that I have it doesn't.

```
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",          
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        url: BASE_URL +  "Contro/Method",
        success: function (data) {
            // success
        }
        ,  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // error
        }
    });
```

For this call, it only passes the model formatted as Json, I suppose it does not work because of contentType: 'application/json', but I don't know if it's this, and what's worse, I don't know how to solve it.

What may be failing and how to solve it?

Comment: Is there a reason for not adding the @guidUser to the Ajax header instead of data? As it is common wouldn't it better to be in the header than in the data? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that option, I'm not sure if I can recover the parameter as I have in mind, but it's worth a try, thanks.
EDIT: I don't think it will work, because I need to add it to the html forms also.