# Creating Task using Wunderlist API

Tags: ajax, json, api, rest, wunderlist

After understanding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925242/start-using-wunderlist-sdk) (guess so) and ended up using the [Wunderlist API](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/endpoints/task), it worked for listing all my lists and listing all my tasks with a given list_id. Now i'm trying to create a task, given a list_id:

```
function create_new_task(){
   list_id = $("#list_id").val(); //Checked for an integer
   title = $("#task_title").val(); //Checked for a string
   $.ajax({
       url: 'https://a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/tasks',
       method: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       headers: { 'X-Access-Token': access_token, 'X-Client-ID': client_id },
       data: {"list_id": parseInt(list_id), "title": title.toString() }
   }).success(function(data){
       $("#create_new_task_modal").modal('hide');
       swal("Task created!", "Your task was successfully created!", "success");
   }).error(handleError);
}
```

But im getting a `400 bad request` with the following non-descriptive error:

```
{"error":"bad_request"}
```

Any one has accomplished this before or can see what am i missing?

Thanks!

Update:

Now im trying to use CURL and it works.. cant find the difference with my $.ajax implementation:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Access-Token: XXX" -H "X-Client-ID: YYY" a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/tasks -X POST -d '{"list_id":1234567,"title":"hellooo"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally!, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155531/converting-curl-cmd-to-jquery-ajax) did the trick.

Apparently i had to set `processData: false` because i needed to send a string as data, not an object. Also changing data to a string instead of an object.