# Using NOAA's V2 API

Tags: jquery, http-headers, token, noaa

I understand C# and VB, but am a bit new to web development. I am trying to write a VB web app to pull data using NOAA's new (V2) API. Their site says to first request a token (done). Then to add it to the header and use a base URL (http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/) and append the appropriate endpoint after v2/...

It then gives me:

```
Header
token

Usage
curl -H "token:<token>" url
OR
$.ajax({ url:<url>, data:{<data>}, headers:{ token:<token> } })
Where <token> is the token obtained from the token request page.
```

My question is:

1. How do they want me to add the token to the header? (I've tried a meta tag, but not sure if I added it properly) and
2. How do I use that jQuery (`$.ajax`) to pull the data I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header they want you to add is not a header in the HTML (i.e. not `<head><meta token=token>`). The header they want is an HTTP header in the request (that's what the `-H` option to curl does).

For JQuery, you pass a header in the options hash:

`$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'token': 'token value' }
});`

Which is what they are showing you under the curl command in the text you pasted:
`$.ajax({ url:<url>, data:{<data>}, headers:{ token:<token> } })`

See more about adding headers to `$.ajax` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for your response! Ok so using JQuery (don't want to try using cURL) I have all three pieces to that $.ajax command, how do I implement $.ajax to get data I need? Do I put it somewhere in my aspx page or in my code behind? Sorry, like I said new to web developing in particular