# Javascript make ajax request without session cookie

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, fetch-api

I'm in firefox. Is there a way in javascript to make an http request with only custom headers? i.e. no cookie fields or user agent or anything, only what my js code specifies.

It should be base js not a library like jquery.

For example, trying to send Http GET without the 'Cookie' header, I tried already:

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open("GET", "http://asite.com");
myRequest.setRequestHeader("Cookie", '');
myRequest.send();
```

But I look in the developer console and the request was still sent with the session cookie. I also tried:

```
myRequest.setRequestHeader("Cookie", null);
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery) ?

Comment: @chayasan srry I should've said, i'd prefer it to be base javascript

Comment: @chayasan there's some non jquery there, but it doesn't seem to guarantee that the ONLY headers that will exist are the ones that I specify, rather it uses setRequestHeader() which modifies/adds an existing one.

Comment: You can use setRequestHeader() in beforeSend method or create a header object and assign your custom key,value pairs.

Comment: @user238905 I tried but it didn't work on 'Cookie' header.

Comment: There are only **some** (very few actually) request headers you can modify (I guess setting them to null/empty may have the effect of removing them) - I can't find the MDN page where I read this some months ago, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fetch()` method which will not include cookies by default (due to `credentials` defaulting to false in most usage scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

Read this: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name

This is a list of headers that can **NOT** be modified/removed in an xmlhttprequest:

`Accept-Charset`
`Accept-Encoding`
`Access-Control-Request-Headers`
`Access-Control-Request-Method`
`Connection`
`Content-Length`
`Cookie`
`Cookie2`
`Date`
`DNT`
`Expect`
`Host`
`Keep-Alive`
`Origin`
`Referer`
`TE`
`Trailer`
`Transfer-Encoding`
`Upgrade`
`Via` or starts with `Proxy-` or `Sec-` (including when it is just `Proxy-` or `Sec-`).