# Backbone Models - change URL query params depending on REST action

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Inside a Backbone model, we have the url and urlRoot attributes:

```
           url: function(){

               return '/jobs'
            },


            urlRoot: function () {

                return '/jobs'
            },
```

however I want to add params or query params to the url, depending on what type of request it is GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

So I want to do something like this:

```
     url: function(type, opts){ //type and opts arguments are not available in Backbone, I just made them up for this example

          var url = '/jobs';

           switch (type) {
              case 'GET':
                break;
              case 'POST':
                break;
              case 'PUT':
                url = url + '?optimisticDelete=' + opts.optimisticDelete;
                break;
              case 'DELETE':
                url = url + '?upsert=' + opts.upsert;
                break;

               default:
                 throw new Error('no match');
                }

          return url;
    },
```

is there a good way to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Backbone models and collections delegate to the `Backbone.sync` function to interact with the server. That's the scope where you will have access to the HTTP method like in your example. You can override the sync function on a model or collection to customize this behavior. Check out the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) and [source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-169) for `Backbone.sync` and [for jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which `Backbone.sync` uses.

I haven't touched Backbone or JavaScript in a while, but I would imagine it would look something like this (this is basically pseudo-code, don't expect it to work as written):

```
sync: function (method, model, options) {
    // method corresponds to the HTTP verb ("type" in your example)
    switch (method) {
      // ...build the correct url like in your example...
    }
    options = options || {};
    options.url = url; // tack correct url onto options object
    return Backbone.sync.apply(this, [method, model, options]);
}
```

It will most likely take more fiddling than this, but hopefully it gets the point across.

Comment: This is totally correct. You need to override sync. Enough exploration in that documentation trvrfrd pointed to will explain why this is correct. This person deserves the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you have is good enough if you can specify the `type` when you create the url.

```
urlExtended: function(type, opts) {
    var url = this.url();

    switch (type) {
    case 'GET':
        break;
    case 'POST':
        break;
    case 'PUT':
        url = url + '?optimisticDelete=' + opts.optimisticDelete;
        break;
    case 'DELETE':
        url = url + '?upsert=' + opts.upsert;
        break;

    default:
        throw new Error('no match');
    }

    return url;
}
```

Downside is 1. need to call urlExtend() yourself when url() is needed, 2. you have to provide the 'type' argument yourslf.

If you don't like that, you could override the Backbone.sync

```
 Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var type = methodMap[method];

    // Default options, unless specified.
    _.defaults(options || (options = {}), {
      emulateHTTP: Backbone.emulateHTTP,
      emulateJSON: Backbone.emulateJSON
    });

    // Default JSON-request options.
    var params = {type: type, dataType: 'json'};

    // Ensure that we have a URL.
    // if (!options.url) {
    //   params.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
    // }

      if (!options.url) {
          if(model.urlExtended) {
              // type is GET, POST...
              // options are what you passed to fetch, save, etc.. as options
              params.url = model.urlExtended(type, options);
          } else {
              params.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
          }
      }
... rest of Backbone.sync code..
```

You could place the above code after you load Backbone to override the sync.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from model attributes if you need control variables then we can also take an entirely different approach and add appropriate headers to the request, that way we don't have to modify the core and invest time in testing.

```
var MyModel = new Backbone.Model();


if(MyModel.isNew()){  //create
  MyModel.save(MyModel.attributes, { headers: { 'create': 'true' }});
}else{
  MyModel.save({}, { headers: { 'upsert': 'true' }});  
}
```

//GET & DELETE can be handled similarly

```
  MyModel.fetch({ headers: { 'get': 'true' }});  

  MyModel.delete({ headers: { 'delete': 'true' }});
```

The above code is untested but should mostly work.

References :

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew

[How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)