# Modify XmlHttpRequest just inside one function of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

I use a jQuery plugin named [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/), which can send ajax requests ([link to the code](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/redactor-rails/redactor.js#L7439-L7490)). My site has an ajax authentication using header. So, I need to set header of all ajax requests, sending via redactor.

How can I modify just this request of the website without modifying the source file?

P.S. I don't need to modify `XmlHttpRequest` globally. I want to modify it just for this chunk of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ajaxSetup()` ( https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/ ). You can define default values for all ajax request in `jQuery`. So you can force the header to requests sent by Redactor.

See this question : [How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

> If you want to add a header (or set of headers) to every request then
>   use the beforeSend hook with $.ajaxSetup():
>
> ```
> $.ajaxSetup({
>     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
>         xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');
>     }
> });
>
> // Sends your custom header
> $.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar' });
>
> // Sends both custom headers
> $.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar', headers: { 'x-some-other-header': 'some value' } });
> ```

Comment: How can I force just one header, no all headers?