# Send Header in window.location.href while redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, web, webrequest, window.location

Is there a way in JavaScript to redirect to a different page with `window.location`, and some sender header.

**Example:**

I redirect from `mypage.com` to `yourpage.com` with a header in the redirect request, and when I reach `yourpage.com`, I should be able to get that header.

Is that possible by any way?

Comment: **Correction**: with `window.location`, and send some header.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding custom header in HTTP before redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671199/adding-custom-header-in-http-before-redirect)