# setting multiple request headers with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a bit of a ridiculous question, but how do I set multiple custom http headers in jquery?

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655768/2554598
explains to do it for one header like:

```
// Request with custom header
$.ajax({
   url: 'foo/bar',
   headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

This works. However

```
// Request with custom header
$.ajax({
   url: 'foo/bar',
   headers: [{ 'my-first-header': 'blub'}, { 'my-second-header': 'peng'}]
});
```

This creates a strange empty header field, containing a json array.

Comment: try `headers: { 'my-first-header': 'blub', 'my-second-header': 'peng'}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Property headers is an object so just try:

```
headers: { 'my-first-header': 'blub', 'my-second-header': 'peng'}
```

Comment: I should have spotted this myself. Thanks very much.