# jQuery AJAX call results in error status 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm trying to make a simple jquery ajax call to API:

**My Code:**

```
$.ajax({
        origin: "*",
        url: 'http://example/test',
        type: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("API_KEY", 'xxx');
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'xxx');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
            }
        });
```

Api working correctly with authorization and return right data but gives error 403 Forbidden when I called it from JQuery ajax.

**Response Header:**

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
>   Expires: -1
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2017 13:00:19 GMT
>   Content-Length: 127

**Request Headers:**

> Accept:*/*
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Cache-Control:no-cache
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Host:sp16-app:2525
>   Pragma:no-cache
>   Referer:http://xxx/test

Comment: You have a syntax error here:
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("API_KEY", 'xxx;
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'xxx');
            },

Comment: Can you post the response headers you are getting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX call results in error status 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666256/jquery-ajax-call-results-in-error-status-403)

Comment: syntax error it just by fault i've updated it @SimonaMi

Comment: i didn't know where to add  **access-control-allow-headers** @StanislavTalanov