# HTTP GET request to server only occasionally works

Tags: javascript, ajax, local-storage, httprequest

I am using jQuery Ajax to make a GET request. Sometimes It works perfectly, but other times I get a 403 forbidden when I look at the chrome dev tools console. Is this a server issue or my code?

When I sign in, I get the encrypted password, username and ID back from the server. I then store that in `LocalStorage` since the request I am trying to get working is on another page. I am also required to make a client token from those fields using AES encryption. For that, I am using `CryptoJS`. For my request, I am required to send in the password, username, ID and client token that has been retrieved from `LocalStorage`. I realize that may not be a good way to go about it, but I do not have control of the server side.

Edit: Here is my Ajax call to the service:

```
 $("#system-form").submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myurl",
        data: "User.Username=" + localStorage.getItem("guid") + "&User.Password=" + localStorage.getItem("password") + "&User.SecUser=" + localStorage.getItem("secUser") + "&ClientAppID=" + localStorage.getItem("ClientAppId") +"&"+ $(this).serialize(),
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        //parse data
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [jQuery AJAX call results in error status 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666256/jquery-ajax-call-results-in-error-status-403)

Comment: `Is this a serve issue or my code?` - yes, probably one of those two

Comment: I have added the code for my `ajax` call.

Comment: I looked at the link taha posted, and I'm not sure how I would use headers. I don't have an api key.

Comment: the server is rejecting your auth parameters. there's not much we can do to help you with that.

Comment: I'm using the same user when testing. Do you know why the server sometimes accept the parameters, and sometimes it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my issue was that I need to URL encode my auth parameters. I fixed this by using `encodeURIComponent`.