# Get post response as json

Tags: javascript, post, github, oauth-2.0

Before I start, I'd like to say sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

I'm trying to setup OAuth2 for GitHub authorization.

I stucked at the step, where I should send POST request to github and receive access token. The problem is that when I send POST request my browser automatically downloads file with access token. Since I can't open this file with javascript, I'm trying to get json as response.

In the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#response) it's written that I can change accept header and receive json, but I can't write correct POST request.

I've already tried a lot of things, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
  dataType: "application/json"
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
     headers: {          
         Accept : "application/json",          
     }     
    data: "data",    
    success : function(response) {  
        console.log(response);  
} })
```

etc

But I get this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load github.com/login/oauth/access_token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://braga.fedyunin.com.ua' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Can't find any useful information in google, so I had to register here. Thanks for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery

Comment: `$.ajax({
url: your_link,
type: "POST",
success:function(response){
console.log(response);
}
})`

Comment: @F.bernal thanks for fast reply. I tried request like in that topic, but I still get this error:

Comment: maybe this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7686916/1816407

Comment: your problem is not in the header to obtain the response in JSON, your problem is in **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://braga.fedyunin.com.ua' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.** You are missing something to authenticate with github.

Answer (score 1):

Read https://developer.github.com/v3/ in section: Cross Origin Resource Sharing

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing, but also failed due to the lack of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response from GitHub API. I contacted GitHub support and found out what was going wrong.

It doesn't work because you are attempting to use OAuth from a web application, which GitHub API does not support. When you authenticate this way, your client_id and client_secret must be in the web page somewhere and sent with the POST request. The entire request, including your client_secret, can be viewed with Firebug or a similar tool. Because it's a bad idea to expose your client_secret, GitHub API will not return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, thus preventing you from retrieving the token.

You must issue the POST from the server side and get the token that way. When you do that, the client_secret is on your server, not in people's browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax request from your site to github.com fails because browsers follow the same origin policy for xhr requests. This means that an xhr request can only be made for a resource on the same origin. 
To allow for cross origin requests, the server needs to Whitlelist domains that can access a particular resource.

In your case, to do this, you need to register your site as an application on your github account, by entering the details here:https://github.com/settings/applications/new

Comment: I have my site registered in github

Comment: Is it with the same protocol that you have registered your application (http)?