# Vaadin flow additional request headers

Tags: java, vaadin, polymer-3.x

In vaadin flow ( version 14! ), how can I add additional request headers to all frontend to server requests? 
For example, i want to add: `xhttp.setRequestHeader("my-token", "abcdef123456");` It is needed, because of some nginx auth settings. 
Thanx for the answers 
Viktor

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any built-in feature for doing this. What you can probably do is to use some JavaScript to override the built-in method that is internally used by Vaadin to send those requests. See [How do I set a default Header for all XMLHTTPRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963758/how-do-i-set-a-default-header-for-all-xmlhttprequests) for an example.