# Add header to XMLHttpRequest (even when encapsulated in IIFE)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, iife, request-headers

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63338231) I asked for a way to automatically add headers to `XMLHttpRequest` objects. I tried to implement [this solution](https://www.diwebsity.com/2015/11/26/intercept-http-requests-ajaxjquery/):

```
(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) 
            { 
                console.log(this.status);
            }
        }, false);
        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
        this.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token 123")
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

This is working working in principle, but not in my case: I want to add a header to some [vendor code](https://github.com/h5p/h5p-editor-php-library/blob/master/scripts/h5peditor-file-uploader.js) that is encapsulated using the IIFE pattern:

```
H5PEditor.FileUploader = (function ($, EventDispatcher) {

    // ...

    self.upload = function (file, filename) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, filename);

        // ...

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // ...

        request.open('POST', H5PEditor.getAjaxUrl('files'), true);
        request.send(formData);
        self.trigger('upload');
    };

    // ...

})(H5P.jQuery, H5P.EventDispatcher);
```

If I add the code from the first code sample inside this IIFE, the header is added. But is there a way to accomplish the same without changing vendor code?

Comment: What do you mean 'without changing vendor code'?

Comment: Vendor code is code that was written by someone else. Typically, web frameworks place it in a `vendor` directory (though in my case, the file in question is then copied to the public directory because it's frontend JavaScript code). I'm looking for a solution that leaves this code untouched.