# php how to tell a ajax post request on apache2.4

Tags: php, ajax, post, apache2.4

I encountered a problem, I am developing a website with `php`, I used to work on the nginx, where I can tell an ajax request by the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` constant.

Recently I switched to `apache2.4`, here I encountered an embarrassing problem, `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` constant is missing, after googling I know I can tell an ajax `get` request by the function `apache_request_headers()`, however it does not work on the ajax `post` request.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: If i remember correctly and it hasen'T change you can add the header in your ajax request. comething like  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php
    function getRequestHeaders() {
        $headers = array();
        foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {

          $header = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))));
          $headers[$header] = $value;
        }
        return $headers;
    }

    $headers = getRequestHeaders();

    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
    }
```

Comment: THX, but it seems that only $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] is enough, thanks anyway.