# API, CORS, MIME, XMLHttpRequest cannot load, issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner programmer/coder, and I've started doing the Local Weather app thing. When trying to get a piece of data from the API I've been struck with these errors (tried .getJSON() first):

1."Access to Font at '...' has been blocked by CORS policy".

2."Bootstrap tooltips require Tether."

3 ".XMLHttpRequest cannot load '...'  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Then I tried a workaround, using .ajax() with jsonp, but then I got hit with these errors:

1."Access to Font at '...' has been blocked by CORS policy".

2.Refused to execute script from '...' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Now I have no idea what to do. Also, I was wondering, why the Tether error came up in the first example, because an hour ago I was not getting this error there and I'm still not getting it in the second example (the one with jsonp).

The `.getJSON()` code: http://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/Mmgzjz

The `.ajax()` code: http://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/oWvMBb

Comment: If API doesn't support CORS or JSONP....you have to use a proxy on your server or third party service. Not all api's can be accessed using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Add required headers in your `AJAX` call.

There are several solutions depending on what you need...

If you want to **add a custom header (or set of headers) to an individual request** then just add the `headers` property:

```
// Request with custom header
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

If you want to **add a default header (or set of headers) to every request** then use `$.ajaxSetup()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});

// Sends your custom header
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar' });

// Overwrites the default header with a new header
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar', headers: { 'x-some-other-header': 'some value' } });
```

If you want to **add a header (or set of headers) to every request**  then use the `beforeSend` hook with `$.ajaxSetup()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');
    }
});

// Sends your custom header
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar' });

// Sends both custom headers
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar', headers: { 'x-some-other-header': 'some value' } });
```

**Edit (more info):** One thing to be aware of is that with `ajaxSetup` you can only define one set of default headers and you can only define one `beforeSend`.  If you call `ajaxSetup` multiple times, only the last set of headers will be sent and only the last before-send callback will execute.

**Reference:** [How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery/14655768#answer-14655768)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header has to be set at other end....does no good setting it  client side

Comment: I recommend you look at docs of openweathermap.org on how to call their API