# How to send a header with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I made a static website and I want to send a request with http header to a `NodeJs Express REST API` with this Ajax function. But when i send it, i can't get any token field by the REST API.

```
 $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("token", 'vjhvjhvjhvjhbjhsbvkjsbvkjsbkvjbskjvb');            
                },
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://localhost:3000/feeds",
                success: function (data) {
                   //do something
                }
            });
```

When i send it with Postman, i can get it easily. Here is the NodeJS middleware

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  console.log(req.headers.token);    
});
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: I don't think you can use `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true` with wildcard `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`

Comment: I have deleted it, but still can't get it.

Comment: Not delete but specify `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "origin you are making requests from"` and add `token` to allowed headers

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "token" is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX headers can be set as global like below.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
   'token':'token_vlaue',
   'another_field': 'another_field_value'
  }
});
```

Comment: thanx but can't get it.

Comment: just add the code which I gave you into document ready function and it will work for all ajax, attach token field.

Comment: I don't know how can i show you all code, but code works fine, he can get json file if i don't use headers

Comment: just put your code [kopy](https://kopy.io/)  and share URL with me. if its working then its good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141573/discussion-between-pandhi-bhaumik-and-adam-jungen).

Comment: Thanx for your hemp Pandhi

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'custom_key': 'custom_value'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    ...
)};
```

Comment: i did now and can't get it.

Comment: Just to clarify, your problem is that you cannot access the backend route you made in your frontend app? Maybe you're using the wrong url?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for token in the wrong code block. You need to setup CORS correctly first, then your token will show up in the correct route later.

Here is an example of the correct pattern to use for CORS.

```
//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,token');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
}

//...
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.get('feeds', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.headers.token);  
    next();
});
```

Comment: That is not the problem, because i have the middleware deleted and send to router.get and there coouldn't get either.

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score -1):

You could try sending it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/feeds",
    headers: { 'token': 'vjhvjhvjhvjhbjhsbvkjsbvkjsbkvjbskjvb' }
});
```

Here is a more detailed answer that may help you: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

Comment: There is no point in linking another answer. If you think the question is duplicate vote to close it as dupliate.