# ajaxSetup not working, its not adding default variable field

Tags: jquery

When I use $.ajaxsetup and trigger $.post, its not adding the default data to the post. or is it only meant for default data if not data supplied?

```
 <script>
    window.csrf = { csrf_token: '<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf_token']; ?>' };
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: window.csrf
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // CSRF token is now automatically merged in AJAX request data.
        $.post('/awesome/ajax/url', { foo: 'bar' }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        data: window.csrf
    });
```

in `document.ready()`.

And like other answers point out, if you want to send `csrf-token`, you have to use `headers` key in `ajaxSetup`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method binding the csrf token if you are using laravel

In head of app.blade.php

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In JS.

```
// CSRF Token

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data in [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method which is overriding the one in ajaxSetup

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )

$.post('/awesome/ajax/url', { foo: 'bar' }, function(data)
```

Instead, you should pass it in headers, Refer [How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery).

HTH