# Ajax not send header form GET request

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have a problem with the `ajax` GET function. I can not send the header from my GET function.
This is my ajax code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function login() {

  $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8085/api/test',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                  xhr.setRequestHeader('token', 'test');
              },
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function () { },
            failure: function () { },
        });
  }
</script>
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

Comment: Please note that `async: false` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `header` property to the object

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8085/api/test',
    headers: {'token': 'test'}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the headers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function login() {

  $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8085/api/test',
            headers: {'token': 'test'}
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function () { },
            failure: function () { },
        });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I still have a problem. The error in console: 
`net::ERR_ABORTED 400`

Comment: Did u try ```headers: {'Authorization': 'test'}``` ?

Comment: The same error. I do not understand where is the problem.

Comment: I Think u are not right write. U should delete  ```async: false```