# rest api authorize using javascript

Tags: javascript, api, authorization

I was trying to create a api web data connector for tableau, but stuck in the authorization phase. I have a header key and value (e.g. api_header, value123) needs to pass using javascript.

```
// Download the data
    myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
        $.getJSON("https://testapi/data",
        
        function(resp) {
        var tableData = [];
```

How to pass the key and value here?

Comment: Have you tried   `$.getJSON("https://testapi/data",
        {api_header:'value123'}
        function(resp) {
        var tableData = [];`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `.getJSON` supports headers, at least [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) doesn't mention them.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655768/1371131), you could use `.ajax` instead like so:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://testapi/data',
  headers: { api_header: 'value123' }
});
```