# Clear cache of contacts after script shared contact API

Tags: javascript, xml, google-contacts-api

I've developed a script that uses Shared Contacts API through URLFecthApp post of XML.
This script is running every 5 minutes since many months to update, create or delete shared contacts (directory contacts).
Since a few days final users cannot display directory contact information. Google temporarily solved the problem cleaning "the cache of the contacts" and suggested me to make a "double check of the code". Now the problem is repeating.
I don't have any error or warning trace and I don't know which cache the support cleans.
Please, have you any suggestion?

Comment: Please, share the response that the final users get from the server to further analyse your situation. Also, to prevent that I miss some details, could you share the code?

Comment: Final users have problems on the shared contacts we create or update via API: when they try to open the entry, in the contact list after a search, they are not be able to open and an empty window is opened and  disappears immediately. While if they scroll the directory list they are able to open the directory contact but they are not able to view the "Note" information. GSuite Support told me is a problem of cache but I don't have any context to verify this (log error, stack error, api report).

Comment: From the har file we export from briwser console of the final user

 "value": "/_/ContactsUi/jserror?script=https%3A%2F%2Fcontacts.google.com%2Fsearch%2Fabate%3Fhl%3Dit&error=Cannot%20read%20property%20%27constructor%27%20of%20undefined&line=Not%20available"

Comment: to share the code I need an email where send it. thank you.

Comment: Hi there @contatti condivisi, you can post the code updating your answer or, if it is too long, you can use an external txt share page and link it here. Since you mention that this could be a cache problem, for how long has this error been occurring? Also please, be aware of the Shared Contacts API limits (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/#Limits) and see if they are getting reached.

Comment: Hi,
     |external txt share page and link it here. 
This is the link for the code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mjkINvzaB6nzAG-uegdVXYzQSO46hnRw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, 
The problem occured at the begin of september. So I called GSUITE support and they exceptionally made a cleaning of our contacts cache. Operation not repeatable. I have no other details.

Comment: HI,
I verified the limits but I'm pretty sure we're not getting reached.

Comment: Hi, The strange thing is that we don't have any problem during the script execution, none log report error or warning.
API dashboard doesn't show error. So all seems to be ok.
The problem is for final user that is not able to see in some case Shared Contact Note Field and in other is not be able to display the directory contact.

Comment: Hi 
This is the link of the empty window
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qjNjxmnRC_3pl31MHCaOCRQ8Swmpe_Df/view?usp=sharing
and the error is that, I pointed out in previous comment

Comment: Hi @contatti condivisi, to discard an interface issue, could you please log the `xmlResponse` of the `getPersonalContact` function and share it?

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron this is an example of a getpersonalcontact XML result and also the XML obtained from the creation of the corresponding shared contact.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DIoBnkGbD_v9deh0KKEVZz3X_qtLdYu1/view?usp=sharing. thank you

Comment: Hello @contatti condivisi, I see no "note" information in those XML transcript, do you mind clarificate me where do you save it? As the documentation says (https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?csw=1#properties) the data is written within the `atom:content` tags.

Comment: Hello @Jacques-GuzelHeron, sorry for my mistake. I meant the "content" field. Final user cannot see the content field.

Comment: Hi @contatti condivisi, I strongly recommend you to contact G Suite support (https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) again, so they can reach you in a way more tailored to your needs. Also, as you can read on the Contacts API documentation (https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/), Google recommends using People API (https://developers.google.com/people). I suggest you to migrate towards this new API if it is possible in your system. Please, be aware that some people report (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28321670) that Contacts doesn't work with the last Javascript libraries.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron. I've already asked twice to the GSUITE support experts. but after a lot of emails, after I shared with them script codes, .har files and videos, they answered me that they cannot give me support for API use. Thank you for the suggestion but with PEOPLE API I cannot search, create, update, delete Directory Contacts (I mean GAL contacts, shared to domain level). I didn't find any other API than https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/ to manage shared contacts and none support. This is not a good thing.