# jQuery JSONP ajax, authentication header not being set

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, jsonp

I'm trying to make an ajax request to the google contacts API with the following setup:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@all",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {
    alt: 'json-in-script'
  },
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  },
  success: function(data, status) {
    return console.log("The returned data", data);
  }
});
```

But the Authentication header doesn't seem to get set. Any ideas?

[image: The request]

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery .ajax does have 'username' and 'password' fields that will do basic auth for you if needed

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@all",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {
    alt: 'json-in-script'
  },
  success: function(data, status) {
    return console.log("The returned data", data);
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token); } 
});
```

EDIT: Looks like it can't be done with JSONP. [Modify HTTP Headers for a JSONP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350778/modify-http-headers-for-a-jsonp-request)

Comment: `xhr.setRequestHeader` doesn't work either. Looks like I need to have a read of the question you linked to.

Answer (score 4):

When authentication is needed in a cross domain request, you must use a proxy server of some sort.

Since using `dataType: jsonp` results in the HTTP request actually being made from the script that gets added to the DOM, the headers set in the `$.ajax` will not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that most of the OAUTH2 REST resources accept the access_token parameter as part of the request url

http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#query-param

please, try the following code instead:

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: url,                
            data: {
                'access_token':token.access_token
            },
            jsonpCallback: 'thecallback',
            success: function(data){
                _cb(data);
            },
            error: function(d){
                _cb(d);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

Just do this (jquery 2.0, but should work in previous versions)

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/test",
        headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + $('#myToken').val()}
    })           
    .done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("error: " + textStatus);
    });
```

Comment: OK, but this is not JSONP ajax request. This is plain ajax request.

Comment: the `headers` option should be valid even if its JSONP. Request headers are part of the HTTP protocol, JSONP is a app/browser level hack.

Comment: @rynop "should be valid" doesn't always means "it is valid", the OP's question is very clear and produceable