# Jersey cors with basic authentication not working

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, cors

Im trying to enable CORS in my jersey web server. I read [this page](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/). So i created my filter

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {


    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
            final ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext
                .getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia, ");

    }

}
```

This is my jQuery test

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: myURL,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.statusText);
            console.log(data.name);
        },
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('login:pass'),
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    });
```

When i run this js it keep asking me the login and password and, even if i type right always return 401 unauthorized.

Comment: BTW im using apache shiro to authentication. When i was testing the webservices through postman i send basic authentication and works, now that im sending through the javascript above the browser keep requesting the login and pass.

Comment: It was my mistake, it wasnt authenticating because of a database connection problem, still i dont know why the browser keep requesting the login and password once i have already passed through the jQuery request.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it, i found out with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24681252/3864677). Just neede to change from

> dataType: 'jsonp',

to

> dataType: 'json',

Since jsonp, ignores the ajax request header.