# JSONP .ajax request with basic authentication

Tags: jquery, jsonp, basic-authentication

I am trying to request a JSONP output from an external API that requires basic authentication.  I have the code below to access it:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://api.example.com/photos/highest-rated?gender=f",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication",
       $.base64.encode(device_id + ":" + secret_key));
   },
   success: function(json) {
       alert('works');
   },
   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert (textStatus);
       alert (errorThrown);
   }
```

The resulting errors are:

```
textStatus = "parsererror"
errorThrown = "Error: jQuery18306713019642047584_1367530194009 was not called"
```

I'm using this jQuery plugin for the Base64 encoding: https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify HTTP Headers for a JSONP request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350778/modify-http-headers-for-a-jsonp-request)