# Getting started with SurveyMonkey api

Tags: javascript, surveymonkey

I'm trying to get started with using the SurveyMonkey api.

```
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?api_key="+apiKey,
        headers:{
          "Authorization": "bearer "+token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body:{
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "analysis_url",
            "preview_url",
            "date_created",
            "date_modified",
            "question_count",
            "num_responses"
          ]
        }   
    })
    .success(createListPicker)
    .error(handleError)
```

I get an error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?api_key=bs579cpsb4mnvn4vh6uqvp2m.
>   The request was redirected to
>   'https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key=bs579cpsb4mnvn4vh6uqvp2m',
>   which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

I'm looking at several different pages about CORS, but can't figure out what the next step is. Any advice?

**The flailing continues**
I've continued to try and figure out jsonp -- but that seems it [can't handle the authorization headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350778/modify-http-headers-for-a-jsonp-request)

I've also tried to use FormData to included the extra authorizations and options [following this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery). It would connect to the api, but then say it couldn't find the authorization token.

I am getting closer with the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key="+apiKey,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','bearer ' + token);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                    } 
    })
     .success(createListPicker)
     .error(handleError)
```

That actually connects and authenticates, but then it returns a status of 3 "Expected object or value". [Status codes documented here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/overview/request-responses/).

Comment: Have you tried updating your request URL to the one you're being redirected to?  (It has an extra `/` before the `?`) - could just be a small misread of the docs, resulting in a redirect that subsequently doesn't work?

Comment: To perform a CORS request, you have to use jsonP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp

Comment: James Thorpe, I just tried that and I get a 404 not found error.

Comment: sudheer -- I'm looking at that thread and don't understand it. Do you use the get_survey_list endpoint and api key and then have a callback function that requests it again? I guess I'm just not clear which parts go in the preflight and which parts then go to actually request the data I'm wanting...

Comment: I would use a different survey tool. Both Examinare developer.examinare.com and SurveyGizmo has a much easier API.

Comment: Unfortunately this is something beyond my control. We have years of survey data in SurveyMonkey and several different departments make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after banging on this for a full day I finally got it working. I used jqueries post with a beforeSend to handle the authentication and JSON.stringify() to deal with the body of the request. Final code looks like:

```
    var obj = {
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "date_created",
            "date_modified",
            "num_responses"
          ],
          "start_date":"2015-12-01 00:00:00"
        }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url:"https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key="+apiKey,
        data:JSON.stringify(obj),
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','bearer ' + token);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                    } 
    })
     .success(createListPicker)
     .error(handleError)
```

Now I need to work out how long the authentication lasts and what happens as I try to drill down to specific information....

Comment: Isn't exposing your Authorization token in client side JavaScript kind of risky?

Comment: Also, how did you get around CORS issues here?

Comment: The beforeSend seemed to be the answer. This was quite awhile ago, so I don't remember all the details. This was for an internal teamsite, so it is behind our company firewall. I wouldn't post that token online.