# Cannot post using Angularjs

Tags: angular, jsonp

I am newbie to angularjs2. Trying to post data on api using `jsonp`. Here I am calling the api :

```
let url = 'http://localhost/TestApp.Web.Api/api/user';
        let body = JSON.stringify(user);
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
        this.jsonp.post(url,body,options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError)
                    .subscribe();
```

I have tested the api through fiddler and it is working fine with the same data.But here if i submit the data it is showing

> Cannot post/register

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using typescript OR javacsript ? Please show bit more code

Comment: AFAIK headers are not supported with JSONP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350778/modify-http-headers-for-a-jsonp-request

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja I am using typescript

Comment: I think your code is something wrong please refer the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2#answer-36289568